# Are there any ways to get sql from getModel?

Tags: magento-1, model, sql

i have this statement, but it runs very low

```
list( $parentId ) = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                        ->getParentIdsByChild( $product->getId() );
```

anyone know how to get the sql it ran? i only know use getSelect() in collection, but how about in Model?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getParentIdsByChild( $product->getId() );    
$parentId->printLogQuery(true);
```

Comment: not working....